# Multiple Users Competing for "Next" Order

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I have an app that calls a SQL Server 2016 stored procedure.  The procedure has a transaction that includes getting the next order from a prioritized list of orders, and then the transaction does additional inserts and updates in an ERP.

The issue I have is when I have more than one of these apps looking for the next order.  It's not difficult for them to query the next order in the stored procedure and get the same order.

Even though the inserts/updates will lock as expected, the select to get the next order will not lock...therefore the scenario of getting the next order is prone for duplicates.

What is the cleanest way of addressing this?  I'd prefer not to apply any custom locking in the transaction for the select if possible.  I've also looked at introducing a table to store what order is being "worked" to prevent any other reads of that same order.  I'm surprised I've never encountered this, so hopefully someone has a clean best practice for this.

Comment: Have you considered using SQL Server's Service Broker? It provides a queuing mechanism out of the box.

Comment: Thanks mweber, but it seems as though that would be over engineering the problem.  I just want to make sure when user x, y, and z ask the stored procedure for the next order, that there's no way they can get the same order back.  Processing of the entire next order transaction takes worst case 10 seconds.  And during that 10 seconds there is a chance users can get the same result from the next order query in the procedure b/c a query doesn't lock a record for another query.

Comment: You could use a Sequence to assign the order to each user, this way it won't repeat.

Comment: My goal was not to over complicate.  My thought was this has to be a common scenario for many, but it looks like this is not all that common.  We just tested the answer below and it works...preventing 2 users from getting the same "next order" from query.  Thanks for all feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The solution took the form of:

query to get next order

- begin trans
- update the database for this order with this criteria
- if no records affected raise error and tell user to try again
- else continue with additional trans inserts and updates for this order
- end trans